# May I be forgiven and ask questions for Christmas?

Tags: support, questions, moderator

I asked to many low quality questions, got a question block and wander if it is in the power of the moderators here to lift blocks? I will make sure my next question is a good one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry Muze, but blocking is something that is done automatically by the system. Moderators have no control over it. All they can do is explain how it works and offer guidance as to how to restore your privileges.

Just work away at doing the little things that will give you full access again, and try to think of it as a learning process.

Comment: I have learned a stupid is a stupid does and you can get shunned here for stupid questions.

Comment: That is why I am trying really hard to sharpen some of IMO also poorly thought out questions.

Comment: Hi @Muze - called2voyage gave you the straight dope. Nobody except a few staff of Stack Exchange knows how the program automatically decides who to block and when to return privileges. Clearly the only way to get out early is to get more votes, but that's all i know, and it's just common sense. You have tried to work on that and it hasn't gone well. I have given you my opinion before about how to make it easier for people here to work with you, and for the most part, you haven't taken that advice. Fair enough. I don't know if it would work anyhow. But that's all we can do - the rest is on you.

Comment: I am trying thanks so much.